# Using Many to Many relations in yii

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many, relation, gii

I am currently trying to display/retrieve data from my database using Yii framework relations which were auto generated by Gii. (MANY_MANY)

User Model contains:

```
return array(
        'memberOfTeams' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'UsersTeam', '{{teamMembers}}(userId, teamId)'),
    );
```

UserTeam Model contains:

```
    return array(
        'teamMembers' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', '{{teamMembers}}(teamId, userId)'),
    );
```

Currently I am working on the User view called profile.php . All I am trying to accomplish is to display the current user with all the teams assigned to him.

teamMembers contains teamId and userId.

How would I write this query?

I have this currently

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList("teamName", 'id', Chtml::listData(UsersTeam::model()->with('teamMembers')->findAll(teamMembers.userId, array($model->id)), 'id', 'teamName'),array('empty'=>'Select Team')); ?>
```

I am able to get all the information if I use findAll(), but I want only teams that the user is assigned to.

Comment: Looks like you've got a good answer from @Mtvw.  I'd also heavily recommend browsing through the Yii forums if you haven't already: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/   Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A project of mine does something similar:

MANY_MANY relation between shop and card, this dataprovider is used to display a list of shops linked to a specific card:

```
$shopDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider( 'Shop',
            array(
                'criteria'=>array(
                    'with'=>array('cardShop'),
                    'condition'=>'cardShop.card_id=:cardId',
                    'params'=>array(':cardId'=>$id),
                    'order'=>'t.id DESC',
                    'together'=>true,
                ),
            )
        );
```